# SPFx Vs Power Apps for building Polls and Forms that are shown inside modern pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, powerapp

I am starting new SharePoint Online project, and we need to add those 2 components inside the site modern home page:-

1. Polls which contain checkboxes to submit >> each user can submit one time. Polls admins will be publishing the Polls and getting their results.
2. Some forms to Submit users feedback

Now i am bit confused if we should develop those as SPFx web part or as Power Apps applications? what is the recommended approach to follow and why?

Atleast we need those to be achievable:-

1. Those components should work on desktop browsers, mobile web browsers & SharePoint mobile application.

Thanks

Comment: How are you storing the information? Are you using an Azure function to accept the request and store the information or will this all be done client side (in the case of SPFx)?

Comment: @CallumCrowley thanks.. SPFx or Power apps will store the Polls questions and answers inside SharePoint

Comment: If the user is adding their response to a list via client side code, there would be no way to control how many responses they actually provide (client side validation using JavaScript isn't enough).

Comment: @Callum Crowley we will use remote event receivers to do server-side validations

Comment: Surely the validation has to happen before the item is created not after (e.g. after a creation event is triggered). Probably be better off using an Azure function and your SPFx application call that.

Comment: @CallumCrowley Yes we can do before add & before update inside remote event receivers ... if we use an Azure function and your SPFx application call that.. then this will not be 100% accurate server-side validation,, as if you do the add using REST api you can overpass the validation.. so RER is the way to go for server-side validation.. but seems this is off-topic..

Comment: Of course it's accurate. The client sends a request to the Azure function via HTTP and the function validates the request server side and returns a response to the client to tell them if it was accepted or not. This is basic web API stuff.

Comment: @CallumCrowley ok and what will happen if you directly call the list RESt API using any of the available tools.. then you will not be calling the azure function... while using RER it will fire regardless of how you call the list, power apps, rest api, list forms .. etc... this is a basic SharePoint stuff.. again this is off-topic to my question

Comment: You wouldn't give the client (user) permissions to the list, they would get an access denied response if they tried to add the content to the list directly. The content would be stored in the list via the function using app only permissions. It's on topic because if you want to use SPFx for a form, you need server side validation and that's what SPFx with an Azure function provides.